# QT QVBoxLayout Determine/Set Visible Area of Scrolling

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, scrollbar, boxlayout

I have a QVBoxLayout which contains content wide enough to require a horizontal scrollbar. I want to be able to set the viewable area (effectively the equivalent of scrolling via the scrollbar) with code.

Nothing within the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qvboxlayout-members.html) strikes me as able to do this -  and I have not been able to easily find ways to retrieve the scrollbar and modify it directly, either.

How can I modify the viewed area of a QVBoxLayout with content larger than the size of the layout?

Comment: You don't want to use QScrollArea, right? The Detailed Description of QAbstractScrollArea might help: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractscrollarea.html

Comment: @DanielCastro I might have to. I would prefer to avoid this, I suppose as it will require a decent amount of code rewrite, but it seems the only way to do such things is not directly with a layout

Answer (score 0):

`QVBoxLayout` doesn't provide any scrolling functionality, so `QScrollArea` would probably be the easiest solution (as was suggested). It may not be as difficult as you think it will be.

Fortunately, scroll areas are fairly easy to use. Here's a simple example that wraps another widget in a scroll area with a horizontal scrollbar:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Force the label to be wide
    QLabel* label = new QLabel("this is a very long label");
    label->setMinimumWidth(300);

    QWidget* widget = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout* layout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
    layout->addWidget(label);

    QScrollArea* scrollArea = new QScrollArea();
    scrollArea->setWidget(widget);

    // Force the scroll area to be smaller
    scrollArea->resize(200, 100);
    scrollArea->show();

    app.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

One tricky thing about scroll areas is controlling their size (not the size of their contents). They define a fixed size hint, so by default, they may not resize as desired. Remember that the outer scroll area's size hint and/or the size policy will determine the way that it resizes within a layout.